# PHP Extracting array with class as value

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

I'm developing an MVC framework and I have a problem with making a flexible code/Structure in declaring helper classes

```
class Controller {
    public $helper = [];

    public function load_helper($helper)    {
        require_once(DIR_HELPER . $helper . '.php');
        $lc_helper = StrToLower($helper);
        $helper_arr[$lc_helper] = new $helper;  
        $this->helper[$lc_helper] = $helper_arr[$lc_helper];    
    }
}
```

//I'm calling the function in my controllers like this

```
Class Home Extends Controller   {

    $this->load_helper('Form');

    $this->helper['form']-><class function>;
}
```

I want to call the function like this:

```
$this->form-><class function>;
```

I can't use extract for public functions but I've seen frameworks that can do it.

I hope someone has an idea and that someone can understand my question, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the magic [`__get`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) method. From the documentation:

> Overloading in PHP provides means to dynamically "create" properties
>   and methods. These dynamic entities are processed via magic methods
>   one can establish in a class for various action types.
>
> The overloading methods are i**nvoked when interacting with properties
>   or methods that have not been declared** or are not visible in the
>   current scope. The rest of this section will use the terms
>   "inaccessible properties" and "inaccessible methods" to refer to this
>   combination of declaration and visibility.

This could be implemented for example this way:

```
class Controller {
    public $helper = [];

    public function load_helper($helper)    {
        require_once(DIR_HELPER . $helper . '.php');
        $lc_helper = StrToLower($helper);
        $helper_arr[$lc_helper] = new $helper;  
        $this->helper[$lc_helper] = $helper_arr[$lc_helper];    
    }

    public function __get($property) {
        //Load helper if not exists
        if (!isset($this->helper[$property])) {
            $this->load_helper($property);
        }

        //Return the helper
        return $this->helper[$property];
    }
}
```

---

Side note:

`Controller::$helper` and `Controller::load_helper()` in my understanding should be `private` or `protected` instead of `public`.

Comment: Thank you sir. Im not used in using magic methods but this one really helped me